# Firebug catches exception in toString() without stack trace

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to track down an odd exception in a JavaScript program. The exception occurs in  `MyClass.prototype.toString()`, where one of the fields of my object is null, causing the method, which references that field, to fail.

I'm using Firebug to debug the situation and I have it set to break on exceptions. The odd thing is that the stack in Firebug lists only the `toString()` method with no calling method. Could someone tell me what that indicates? Other exceptions show the stack just fine. Perhaps Firebug itself is trying to evaluate a `toString()` for debug information, and then causing the error? I should mention I'm working primarily with another author's code base, so I'm looking for general help that may help me track it down.

(If it matters I'm using a few external libraries, including jQuery.)

Comment: Do you have a URL to a test case, so the problem can be reproduced? Which version of Firebug and Firefox?

Comment: Can you `console.log(MyClass.prototype.toString())`?